# cannot insert contacts in sqlite3 database

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

```
-(IBAction)saveData:(UIButton *)sender { 
    sqlite3_stmt *statement; 
const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String]; 

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK) 
{ 

    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO CONTACTS (name , password , email) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")",
                          self.theName.text ,self.thePass.text,self. Email.text]; 

    const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String]; 

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL); 

    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) 
    { 
        self.theStatus.text = @"Contact added"; 
        self.theName.text = @""; 
        self.Email.text = @""; 
        self.thePass.text = @""; 
    }
    else { 
        self.theStatus.text = @"Failed to add contact"; 
    } 
    sqlite3_finalize(statement); 
    sqlite3_close(contactDB); 
}}
```

i am using this code to insert my data in the `sqlite` database. But it always shows the same answer "failed to add contact".

Comment: Check the return status from `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` and `sqlite3_step()` and report the error using `sqlite3_errmsg()`.  That will give you a clue.

Comment: sir i am getting no idea. please can u explain me in detail??

Comment: No idea about what?  If you are unable to add error-reporting to this method then you have much greater issues ahead of you and it sounds like you are running before you can walk.

Comment: using your recomendation,i have message that table is created.i am new in ios developming

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get all error messages you need

```
-(IBAction)saveData:(UIButton *)sender { 
sqlite3_stmt *statement; 
const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String]; 

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK) 
{
    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO CONTACTS (name , password , email) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")",
                          self.theName.text ,self.thePass.text,self. Email.text]; 

    const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String]; 

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) 
        { 
            self.theStatus.text = @"Contact added"; 
            self.theName.text = @""; 
            self.Email.text = @""; 
            self.thePass.text = @""; 
        }
        else { 
            NSLog(@"sqlite3_step failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(contactDB));
            self.theStatus.text = @"Failed to add contact"; 
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"sqlite3_prepare_v2 failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(contactDB));
    }

    sqlite3_close(contactDB); 
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"sqlite3_open failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(contactDB));
}
}
```

This might not be error free as I can't test its compilation, but this gives you an idea of how you get errors.

Comment: imotep in ur code i am gerring error "expected error before else"at @@ NSLOG (@"sqlite3_prepare_v2 failed .....")

Comment: what was your problem?

Comment: my table was not created